# Validate nested field in dynamic form with remote server validation net core jquery/knockout

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, formwizard

I have a bootstrap wizard with 3 tabs, and in the second tab i have a dynamic contact form where i can add as many "contacts" as i want.

Inside the contact i have an email field i'd like to validate against the server (for duplicate items in database) and a checkbox.

My code behind for the validation is quite simple :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CheckEmail([FromBody] string email)
    {
        var exists = await _userManager.CheckEmailAsync(email);

        return exists ? Json(false) : Json(true);
    }
```

In the viewModel i have a knockout validation rule :

```
ko.validation.rules['isEmailUnique'] = {
    validator: function(val, param) {
        var isValid = true;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: '/Supplier/SupplierManagement/CheckEmail',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(val),
            success: function(response) {
                isValid = response;

            },
            error: function() {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });
        if (isValid) {
            $(".wizard .actions a[href='#next']").show();
        } else {
            $(".wizard .actions a[href='#next']").hide();
        }
        return isValid === param;
    },
    message: emailAlreadyExistsInDatabase
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

I'm hiding the wizard next step on this because whenever the errors displays on the view it doesnt block the Next button.

I extend the contact at creation using this function :

```
function addContactViewModel() {
var contact = ko.mapping.fromJS(emptyContactJson);
contact.email = ko.observable(contact.mail);
contact.email = ko.observable().extend({ isEmailUnique: true });
viewModel.contacts.push(contact);
```

}

And my part of my view :

I have a panel with lots of crap around it so i'm posting only the relevant bits

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 padding-label"email</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="email" data-bind="value: contact.email,attr: { name:'email-' + $index()}" />
    <span data-bind='visible: contact.email.hasError, text: contact.email.validationMessage'> </span>
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 padding-label">Primary</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <label class="style-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="primarycheckbox" onchange="$('#languageselector').attr('disabled', !this.checked)" data-bind="value: contact.primaryContact" /><span></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

The checkbox also activate a language selector for the interface since a primary contact will be the one connecting to my site.

My problems :

1. I'd like to validate that only ONE checkbox of all the contacts can be checked, but also one need to be checked among all of the contacts.
2. The email validation error displays on the view but    doesnt block the next button, that's why i disabled it in the    validation rule, i'd like something cleaner
3. I did this with knockout for email validation but i have lots of validation using jquery but coundnt find anything for dynamic remote    form validation on nested items in jquery
4. The email preferably would only need to be validated if the primary checkbox is checked, at the same time email would not even be    required if the checkbox is not checked